# Return selected letter in hololens keyboard using Unity

Tags: c#, hololens, unity-editor

so I am super new to unity and hololense, but I wanted to get an idea for how to add this specific feature. I want to be able to print the individual letter that is selected as the user moves through the hololens keyboard. So for example, if the user moves across the middle of the keyboard, the application should print a new line for every letter that is selected and it would look something like below.

Selected: a
Selected: s
Selected: d
....
Selected: j
Selected: k
Selected: l

I have done some research into this, but the closest thing I have found is the getkey() method, but from what I understand for that method the user needs to actually click the individual letter for it to be registered. From what I read from the Unity forum, this feature looks to be feasible, but I haven't found any specifics on how to do it. I'd really appreciate any suggestions. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

We recommend you use the [Non-Native Keyboard](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/ReleaseNotes.html#whats-new-in-230) of MRTK2.3 to make things easier. You just need to implement [`IPointerEnterHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html) interface for `KeyboardValueKey` class in KeyboardValueKey.cs script:

```
public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Debug.Log("Select: " + Value);
}
```

This method is called when the pointer has hovered over a certain GameObject.  Besides, if you are not familiar with NonnativeKeyboard, the example scene, in MixedRealityToolkit.Examples\Experimental\NonnativeKeyboard\Scenes\NonNativeKeyboardExample, will show how to use Non-Native Keyboard .

Comment: Hi Hernando, thank you for your reply. Quick question though, is it possible to complete this with the standard keyboard, that is a bit of a necessity for the application. Also if you have any sort of sample program that implements this methid it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, only the letter of the key currently holds down can be got by API getkey(), and Unity does not provide an API to get the key that is focused. It may be difficult to implement this idea with Native Keyboard.